# How can I prevent a change event from being fired from a selected radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire a change event for a selected group radio button but this event gets fired if I select an already selected radio button.  Can I prevent this from happening?

```
$("input[type='radio']").mouseup(function(){
    ... 
}).change(function(){
    ...
});
```

HTML

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
            Option one
</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
            Option two
</label>
```

Comment: `change` event is [fired correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/a9ZQ6/), that is when radio button is changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[type='radio']:not(:selected)").mouseup(function(){
    ... 
}).change(function(){
    ...
});
```

OR

```
$("input[type='radio']:not(:checked)").mouseup(function(){
    ... 
}).change(function(){
    ...
});
```

`:not(:selected)` will exclude all `selected` `radio`s.

Read about **[`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)** and **[`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selectors.

Comment: I just had to change :selected to :checked and that solved my issue.  Thanks!